# Vuejs prop validation with multiple types and typed arrays

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

Using Vuejs 3 and Typescript, the goal is to get a prop to be of type `string | string[]`. Looking at [the docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html#prop-validation), it looks like I should be able to set a prop using multiple types like so:

```
props: {
    prop1: {type: [String, Array], default: ""}
}
```

Looking at a [Vetur commit](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/commit/fbd21c8d7bd054a9e5a72a8182e9a66af7b18571) and [the docs again](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#annotating-props), it looks like I should be able to set an array prop type like so:

```
props: {
    prop1: {type: Array as PropType<string[]>, default: []}
}
```

I can get both of these to work individually no problem, but when I try to combine them I get an error:

```
props: {
    prop1: {type: [String, Array as PropType<string[]>], default: ""}
}

No overload matches this call.
The last overload gave the following error.
    Type '{ type: (StringConstructor | (new (...args: any[]) => string[] & object) | (() => string[]) | PropConstructor<string[]>[])[]; default: string; }' is not assignable to type 'PropOptions<unknown, unknown> | (new (...args: any[]) => object) | (() => unknown) | PropConstructor<unknown>[] | null'.
    Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
        Type '(StringConstructor | (new (...args: any[]) => string[] & object) | (() => string[]) | PropConstructor<string[]>[])[]' is not assignable to type 'true | (new (...args: any[]) => object) | (() => unknown) | PropConstructor<unknown>[] | null | undefined'.
        Type '(StringConstructor | (new (...args: any[]) => string[] & object) | (() => string[]) | PropConstructor<string[]>[])[]' is not assignable to type 'PropConstructor<unknown>[]'.
            Type 'StringConstructor | (new (...args: any[]) => string[] & object) | (() => string[]) | PropConstructor<string[]>[]' is not assignable to type 'PropConstructor<unknown>'.
            Type 'PropConstructor<string[]>[]' is not assignable to type 'PropConstructor<unknown>'.
                Type 'PropConstructor<string[]>[]' is not assignable to type '() => unknown'.
                Type 'PropConstructor<string[]>[]' provides no match for the signature '(): unknown'.
```

I'm not sure what's different between the array syntax for defining types and just using the `PropType` thing directly, but it's very unhappy about something there.  I'm also a bit confused by the unknown stuff mentioned in the error as I would expect everything to be either strings or arrays.

Comment: default value should be a callback returning a empty array

Comment: is that necessary for using the `type: []` syntax?  Default value can certainly be a plain string in other locations.  Also, changing it to: `default: () => []` gives the same error

Comment: with TS you can do it i sure, but with js idk

Comment: Does `prop1: {type: [String, Array], default: (): string | string[] => ''}` work?

Comment: @tao not really. It makes the type be `string | undefined[]` which isn't what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
props: {
    prop1: {type: [Array, String] as PropType<string[] | string>, default: ""}
}
```

It seems like you have to cast the entire type, otherwise you get the warnings. Also it seems `Array` defaults to `uknown[]` type